# Adding in String and int to parent class with super.toString

Tags: java, string, class, super

Okay, so I have 4 different classes for my program, and I'm trying to add a new variable in one of my subclasses. I will show the code for all of the classes involved and then explain what exactly is wrong.

First Code is my Person Class:

```
class Person {
private String myName; // name of the person
private int myAge; // person's age
private String myGender; // 'M' for male, 'F' for female

// constructor
public Person(String name, int age, String gender) {
    myName = name;
    myAge = age;
    myGender = gender;
}

public String getName() {
    return myName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return myAge;
}

public String getGender() {
    return myGender;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    myName = name;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    myAge = age;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    myGender = gender;
}

public String toString() {
    return myName + ", age: " + myAge + ", gender: " + myGender;
}
```

}

my next class is my Teacher Class:

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
private static int salary;
private static String subject;

public Teacher(String name, int age, String gender, String subject, int salary) {
    super(name, age, gender);
    //Constructor
    salary = salary;
    subject = subject;
    public String toString(){


    return super.toString() +", Subject: " + subject + " Salary: " + salary;
}
}
```

}

So the problem with my program is, I'm trying to add in the String Subject and the Int Salary. I'm getting an error that keeps saying "Syntax error on token "String", @ expected"(Line 12 of the Teacher Class) and then another one right next to it saying:""Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement"(line 12 of the Teacher Class).

So all I am trying to do is add the new values into my parent class so that when I go to add in a user I can enter their salary and subject and so on. Sorry if i'm not too clear. It might be in plain sight for some of you, if i'm not clear enough please let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Sully

Comment: Please indent your code. It's very hard to read at the moment. Also, you've presented a *lot* of code, when I suspect you could have shown a complete example in very few lines...

Comment: I'm sorry. The formatting was messing my code up :/  I'm not too sure how to fix this, i'll try to give the minimum amount of code possible.

Comment: Why are salary and subject static?

Comment: Move your toString out of the constructor.                                                                    public Teacher(String name, int age, String gender, String subject, int salary) {
    super(name, age, gender);
    //Constructor
    salary = salary;
    subject = subject;
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                public String toString(){


    return super.toString() +", Subject: " + subject + " Salary: " + salary;
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't looked all through your code, but I believe this is the problem:

```
public Teacher(String name, int age, String gender, String subject, int salary) {
    super(name, age, gender);
    //Constructor
    salary = salary;
    subject = subject;
    public String toString(){

    return super.toString() +", Subject: " + subject + " Salary: " + salary;
}
```

You've started overriding `toString` in the middle of the constructor. You need to close the constructor, then start the `toString` method:

```
public Teacher(String name, int age, String gender, String subject, int salary) {
    super(name, age, gender);
    //Constructor
    salary = salary;
    subject = subject;
}

public String toString() {    
    return super.toString() + ", Subject: " + subject + " Salary: " + salary;
}
```

Ideally, use the `@Override` annotation to tell the compiler to validate that you really *are* overriding a superclass method, too:

```
@Override
public String toString() {    
    return super.toString() + ", Subject: " + subject + " Salary: " + salary;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One issue is:

```
public Teacher(String name, int age, String gender, String subject, int salary) {
    super(name, age, gender);
    //Constructor
    salary = salary;
    subject = subject;
    public String toString(){


    return super.toString() +", Subject: " + subject + " Salary: " + salary;
}
}
```

Your `toString()` method is inside constructor. Move it to outside the constructor.

```
public Teacher(String name, int age, String gender, String subject, int salary) {
        super(name, age, gender);
        //Constructor
        salary = salary;
        subject = subject;
    }

   public String toString(){
       return super.toString() +", Subject: " + subject + " Salary: " + salary;
    }
```